# "audio/m4a" mime type not supported Android 11

Tags: java, android, mediastore, android-11

What I am trying to do: Using Mediastore Api to download and retrieve audio from Sdcard.(Android 11)

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "menuCategory");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/m4a");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+"/DownloadMyMusic");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, trackStoreDTO.getArtistName());
Uri uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);     
OutputStream outputStream = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
```

I am getting error for line 3 stating: "audio/mp4" mime type not supported, I assumed I might be doing something wrong so I created a sample app and it works totally fine android 11, I have searched everything and totally clueless right now, any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: you can check supported media format in following [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats)

Comment: yeah I checked that one actually, m4a is supported acc. to doc, also in sample app same audio works totally fine with same media format @Bhavin

Comment: Did you try with `audio/*` ?

Comment: Giving this error: Unsupported MIME type audio/* @SagarBalyan

Comment: Okay. Will have to look, try reading the docs properly. I can't spend much time here as i myself am stuck with something and have myself asked a question on SO which i am waiting the answer for.  Or better yet....You answer my question, i will answer yours. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70662424/android-ble-stopadvertisingset-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how it actually worked, but stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/frostwire/frostwire/issues/957) and changed

```
Uri uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);     
to Uri uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY), values);
```

and it's working, in case anyone get's stuck on the same.

Comment: it's not a solution really, it's more a hack