# Android BLE stopAdvertisingSet() not working

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am advertising using a `advertising set` in my android app. Here is the code:

```js
AdvertisingSetParameters advertisingSetParameters = new AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder()
  .setLegacyMode(false).setPrimaryPhy(PHY_LE_CODED).setSecondaryPhy(PHY_LE_CODED).setConnectable(true).setScannable(false).build();
mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertisingSet(advertisingSetParameters, data, null, null, null, new AdvertisingSetCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onAdvertisingSetStarted(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet, int txPower, int status) {
        super.onAdvertisingSetStarted(advertisingSet, txPower, status);
        showToast(context, "Extended Advertising Started");
      }
    }
```

Advertising starts and works fine.

However, when i try to stop this `advertising`, it never gets stopped and even my `callback` does not get called.

```js
mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.stopAdvertisingSet(new AdvertisingSetCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onAdvertisingSetStopped(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet) {
    super.onAdvertisingSetStopped(advertisingSet);
    Constants.LOGS = "Extended Advertising Stopped" + "\n\n" + Constants.LOGS;
    Constants.CONNECTION_LOGS = "Extended Advertising Stopped" + "\n\n" + Constants.LOGS;
    mStatus = "Extended Advertising Stopped";
    updateLogs(Constants.LOGS, mStatus);
    showToast(context, "Extended Advertising Stopped");
  }
});
```

In the above code i am trying to stop the advertising set but `onAdvertisingSetStopped` is never called. Nor do i get any error or exceptions.

Any ideas as why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the things you do in `onAdvertisingSetStarted` may cause `onAdvertisingSetStopped` to not fire (for example, the `showToast` call there). In my case I had tried to do a broadcast in `onAdvertisingSetStarted` after which `onAdvertisingSetStopped` was never invoked. As soon as I removed the broadcast, `onAdvertisingSetStopped` started firing. You could try temporarily commenting out your implementation of `onAdvertisingSetStarted` and see if that helps.